# Multiple MongoDB collection names for the same Java class

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongorepository

I am using Spring's MongoRespository. I have one class but it is called by two methods and I want to store that class in Mongo based on which method called it. How would I differentiate how it was used by having two different collections based on that one class in mongo?

Right now I have my have two repository interfaces in my dao.

```
public interface PastOpportunityRepository extends MongoRepository<DMOpportunity, String>,       CustomPastOpportunityRepository {}
```

and

```
public interface PredictiveOpportunityRepository extends MongoRepository<DMOpportunity, String>, CustomPredictiveOpportunityRepository {`
```

I want to avoid making two differently named classes with the same code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest using `Springs MongoTemplate` that has overloads that take the collection name.

[MongoTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html)

[MongoTemplate.find(Query query,               Class entityClass,               String collectionName)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#find(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String))

[MongoTemplate.insert(Object objectToSave,          String collectionName)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#insert(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I am using that. But I'm having trouble with having two collection names for one java class.

Comment: Use two different collection names, one in `PastOpportunityRepo` and the other in `PredictiveOppRepo`

Comment: How do I do that? I tried using `@Document(collection = "name")` on both and the collection name defaulted to my class name

Comment: Dude! Look at my post! The signatures I linked allow you to explicitly pass a `collectionName`. This allows you to store any Spring Data object to any collection or any number of collections by providing the name of the collection.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was really stupid, ignore it.