# Working with multiple collections using one MongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Spring Data MongoDB repository:

```
interface AssertionEventRepository extends MongoRepository<AssertionEvent, Long> {
```

I want to use it to store documents in 2 different collections, but without creating additional subinterfaces. I'm not using `MongoTemplate` directly so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24995698/3263204) doesn't apply. How can I achieve that?

I'm using a `@Configuration` extending the `AbstractMongoConfiguration`.

Comment: You can't do it with single repository.