# How can I store to different collections with MongoRepository depending on type of generic in document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.6. Especially, I am using [Spring Boot Data MongoDB](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb) for the connection to MongoDB.

Assume I have this `MongoRepository`

```java
public interface MyRepository1 extends MongoRepository<MyDocumentClass<MyResult1>, String> {
}
```

and a second one

```java
public interface MyRepository2 extends MongoRepository<MyDocumentClass<MyResult2>, String> {
}
```

Then I have my document

```java
@Document(collection = "collectionName")
public class MyDocumentClass<T extends AbstractResult> {

    private String myString;
    private int myInt;
    private List<T> results;

    public MyDocumentClass(String myString, int myInt, List<T> results) {
        this.myString = myString;
        this.myInt = myInt;
        this.results = results;
    }

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public int getMyInt() {
        return myInt;
    }

    public List<T> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

And of course `AbstractResult` as well as `MyResult1` and `MyResult2` extending it.

Before, `MyDocumentClass` wasn't generic. Then the code worked fine. But now I want to choose a different collection name based on what `T` is in `MyDocumentClass`. Is that possible? If yes, how?

If have already found [a way using MongoTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995595/multiple-mongodb-collection-names-for-the-same-java-class), but that is not what I am looking for here.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by placing MyResult1 and MyResult2 inside a MyDocumentClass? Since Ideally the @Document annotation will best suit if used in MyResult classes to achieve what you need.

Comment: Well, this is a (probably not good enough) minimal example. `MyDocumentClass` holds more information, that's why.

Comment: I edited it to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that because of java's [Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Generics are only visible at compile type. Thus on runtime the JVM cannot differentiate between `MyDocumentClass<MyResult1>` and `MyDocumentClass<MyResult2>`.

You can however store these instances in the same `MongoRepository<MyDocumentClass, String>`.

Comment: Ok, but if I do that, I still can't store them in different collections, is what you're saying? The only way I could is to have two different `MyDocumentClass`with two different `@Document annotations`, holding two different result types?

Answer (score 1):

As you had found out, you can do it using `MongoTemplate`, but the question isn't how you'd do it; it's should you do it. I'd say no; Java is not C++ - `MyDocumentClass<MyResult1>` and `MyDocumentClass<MyResult2>` are not different things. Generics in Java is merely a compile time qualifier.

There are more than one ways to discriminate between `MyResult1` and `MyResult2` but the easiest is probably to add a type in `MyDocumentClass`. Something like:

```
public class MyDocumentClass {
    private String type = "MyResult1 or MyResult2";
}
```

Comment: How does this solve my problem about the collection name though?

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff like I said, changing collection names don't fit here. So, it solves your problem by not changing collection names

Comment: And store everything in the same collection, is what you're saying?

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff, yes with `type` being the differentiator.